# A question on a condition potentially implying uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

If I have a sequence of continuous functions $\{ f_n(x) \}$, all of which are non-negative, satisfying

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{x \in A} f_n(x) = \sup_{x \in A} \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = K < \infty$$

and $f_n(x) \to f(x)$, where $f$ is continuous. Under what additional conditions, if any, may I say $f_n(x)$ converges uniformly to $f(x)$?

Comment: You can't even say that $f_n$ converges pointwise to $K$ with these conditions. Consider $f_n(x) = 0$ for all $x\neq c\in A$ and $f_n(c) = K > 0$. Then, $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sup_{x\in A} f_n(x) = \sup_{x\in A}\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(x) = K$, but $f_n$ doesn't converge pointwise to $K$.

Comment: Apologies. $f_n$ are continuous.

Comment: Even with continuity, you can't say that $f_n$ converges pointwise to $K$. Consider, for example, an $A$ in some normed vector space such that $0\in A$, and let $f_n(x) = \frac{K}{1+n\|x\|}$ (which is continuous for all $n$). Then, $f_n$ is bounded above by $K$ and converges pointwise to $0$ everywhere except at $x = 0$, and $f_n(0) = K$ for all $n$.

Comment: You're making me realize there is a typo in my question. See above.

Comment: Reading the revised question, I still don't think there are any nice conditions you can add that are weaker than the uniform convergence condition to ensure that $f_n\to f$ uniformly. With the conditions as they are, it's possible to construct all sorts of examples such that $f_n$ converges to a discontinuous $f$, which contradicts uniform convergence (if $f_n\to f$ uniformly and $f_n$ is continuous for all $n$, then $f$ is continuous).

Comment: In my case, $f$ is continuous. I guess I really didn't type this out carefully.

Comment: Okay, now we're getting somewhere. Now, if $A$ is compact and $f_n$ is monotone (meaning $f_n\geq f_{n-1}$ everywhere for all $n$ or $f_n\leq f_{n-1}$ everywhere for all $n$), then you have uniform convergence. This is called Dini's theorem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63760/discussion-between-johnny-apple-and-michael-lee).